# Replacing "/\ characters with sed, from within php

Tags: php, sed

I generate password from php (thru web page) using shell_exec / dd/ /dev/urandom.
I want to eliminate
`"/\`
characters from my generated password.

If I do a replacement in my sed line with

`'s/["/\]/!/g'`

the script fails to execute. However I tested this from command line like

`echo "this /is \"a \test" | sed -e 's/["/\]/!/g'`

Then I get the right result : this !is !a !test

If I eliminate this replacement section from my sed line, php script does execute properly. What seems to be the issue? I thought characters within brackets [] is safe and does not need escaping.. is that the issue?

Comment: Add in your question how you generate the password (no comment).

Comment: I suggest generating passwords that do not contain the unwanted characters in the first place.

Comment: Show us the code that generates the password. https://xyproblem.info

Comment: Escape the chars correctly, ``sed 's/[\"/\\]/!/g'``

Comment: And the oscar goes to Wiktok Stribizew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP, if you use the command in a double quoted string literal, you need to escape the `"` with a single backslash, `\"`, and the backslash inside the bracket expression must also be escaped.

In the end, this must look like

```php
sed 's/[\"/\\]/!/g'
```

Comment: Yes I should've provided the password generation line but yes, I am using  double quotes shell_exec("dd if=/dev/urandom .....| base64 |  sed '  ......' ")